# How do I execute custom code before IControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance() is called?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap

I need to execute some custom code before `IControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance()` is called.

I have looked at using `HtppApplication.BeginRequest` event, but that would execute my code for *every* request made to the server (include requests for static resources) - not ideal.

Is there an extensibility point in MVC that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: if you don't want to call it on `BeginRequest` when do you want to run it? `ApplicationStart`?

Comment: After `BeginRequest`, ideally. I *could* run it within `BeginRequest`, but I don't want it to execute for static resource requests, if possible.

Comment: So you only want to run it on Controller requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot think why you need to do this, however, I think the simplest would be to create your own `IControllerFactory`. In MVC3, there is also new interface `IControllerActivator`.

```
public interface IControllerActivator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// When implemented in a class, creates a controller.
    /// </summary>
    IController Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType);
}
```

Here is an example using Unity,

```
public class UnityControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="UnityControllerFactory"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="container">The container.</param>
    /// <param name="controllerActivator">The controller activator.</param>
    public UnityControllerFactory(IUnityContainer container, IControllerActivator controllerActivator)
        : base(controllerActivator)
    {
        ////Guard.ArgumentNotNull(container, "container");
        _container = new PerRequestUnityContainer(container);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Releases the specified controller.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controller">The controller to release.</param>
    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        if (controller != null)
        {
            _container.Teardown(controller);
        }

        base.ReleaseController(controller);
    }
}

public class UnityControllerActivator : IControllerActivator
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public UnityControllerActivator(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        ////Guard.ArgumentNotNull(container, "container");
        _container = new PerRequestUnityContainer(container);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When implemented in a class, creates a controller.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The created controller.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="requestContext">The request context.</param><param name="controllerType">The controller type.</param>
    public IController Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        ////Guard.ArgumentNotNull(requestContext, "requestContext");
        ////Guard.ArgumentNotNull(controllerType, "controllerType");

        // do what ever you need to before creating your controller

        IController controller = (IController)_container.Resolve(controllerType);
        return controller;
    }
}
```

and somewhere in your startup/boot strapping process,

```
IUnityContainer container = ...;

// resolve our factory (and any of it's dependencies)
IControllerFactory factory = container.Resolve<IControllerFactory>();
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(factory);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I'd run the code through a Custom `BaseController`

```
public class BaseController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    public BaseController()
    {
    }

    protected override System.Web.Mvc.IActionInvoker CreateActionInvoker()
    {
        // Call Custom Code Here

        return base.CreateActionInvoker();

    }
}
```

From there, you inherit from the base controller whenever you need to.

```
public class MyController : MyApp.BaseController
{

}
```

Comment: That's a possibility, but I want avoid using a base controller when possible.